# where could i find adb driver for motog xt1033 mobile phone?

Tags: android, eclipse, drivers

where could i find ADB driver for (motog xt1033) mobile phone? I just downloaded Samsung ADB drivers. But could anyone suggest where could i find adb drivers for other phone? Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please do [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) the Community guidelines before posting questions that are off-topic to this site.

If you are looking for `USB Driver` to test on a hardware device, Consider reading [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) .

Motorola's Developer resources are found [here](http://www.motorola.com/us/Motorola-Developers/motorola-developers.html).